# corelDraw 6 add-in

Tags: visual-studio-2010, add-in, coreldraw

Thank you for taking some time to check my question,
so I need to build corelDraw 6 add-in using VB.NET

### so I take 2 ways (1) just try to use VSTA editor ,but didn't work :( I got this error, try to switch .NET version to 3 or 2 but didn't work too, just show the following message  >>>>>>>>>>

### CorelDRAW

Unable to attach. Check for one of the following.

1. The application you are trying to debug uses a version of the Microsoft .NET Framework that is not supported by the debugger.
2. The debugger has made an incorrect assumption about the Microsoft .NET Framework version your application is going to use.
3. The Microsoft .NET Framework version specified by you for debugging is incorrect.

### Please see the Visual Studio .NET debugger documentation for correctly specifying the Microsoft .NET Framework version your application is going to use for debugging.

any advice ...?

(2) I used my VS 2010 and created a class library project ,then used the code in the VSTA and inserted all related references to corelDraw -> build -> all goes well I got my dll file :( but how to make it work as add-in inside corelDraw 6

any advice ...?

Thank you So much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooh I just solve it :)

I copy the dll file which I did using VS2010 in C:\Users\\Documents\Corel\VSTA\CorelDRAW\Addins

re-open corel and it just worked, thank you all

any idea answer about way (1) will be reate too, thank you